# Can't return null (System.Boolean cannot be null)

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I want to return int and bool values to WP page from the database using WCF service. When those fields in the database are `null` I'm getting an exception:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:someFuncResult. The InnerException message was
>   'ValueType 'System.Boolean' cannot be null. Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

With int type I have the same problem.

Piece of my database looks like:

```
[boolValue]    BIT    NULL,
[intValue]     INT    NULL,
```

My service implementation:

```
     public someClass someFunc(int check)
    {
return (from a in datacontext.someTable
                where a.number == check
                select new someClass ()
                {
                    intValue2 = (int?)a.intValue ,
                    boolValue2 = (bool?)a.boolValue,                
                }).Single();
    }
```

My service interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
   someClass someFunc(int check);

    [DataContract]
        public class someClass 
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int? intValue2 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool? boolValue2 { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Did you introduce the `Nullable<bool>` field recently, you might want to update the reference on client side for your service. It seems that the proxy is still expecting a `bool` and not a `bool?`

Comment: Are you binding to a WS (SOAP) service?  SOAP doesn't always handle nullables too well.

Comment: @Habib, I had an error in my service implementation code and it wasn't updating. Thank you, it worked now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Nullable<bool>` field was introduced recently, reference on client side for my service wasn't updated. After updating the reference it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the database null is different then standard null

use this function

```
 static bool ConvertToBool(object Dnull)
        {
            try
            {
                DBNull a = (DBNull)Dnull;
                string u = a.ToString();

                if (u.Length > 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

and

```
bool Isnull = ConvertToBool(_sqldatareader["Name"]);
```

this work fine for in mysql.

Comment: this is just the idea DBNull is not convertible directly i needed urgent